# Is insert.addBatch() accessible outside of this for loop?

Tags: java, sql, for-loop, prepared-statement

I have multiple for loops where I am setting the values to be inserted into a MySQL DB. 
 My question is will insert.addBatch(); detect the insert values if it is outside of the for loop. Below is an example:

```
List<String> lstUser = usageEvent.getUserName();
List<String> lstFullName = usageEvent.getFullName();
List<String> lstUserType = usageEvent.getUserType();

for(String userName : lstUser) {
            insert.setString(1, userName);
        }
for(String fullName : lstFullName) {
            insert.setString(2, fullName);
        }
for(String userType : lstUserType) {
            insert.setString(3, userType);
        }
insert.addBatch();
```

Edit: Added extra code above to show that I am casting from a list to a string to obtain the values. I am not sure if this will change the approach to the question.

Comment: No, it will not. If you use an IDE, it'll report a compilation error.

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: @lealceldeiro what do you suggest i do to fix it?

Comment: Is size of those collections always the same? If so, just create one simple `for` loop, and add them one by one

Comment: @Amongalen I dont have db connectivity to try it, and yes the size of the collections is the same so I can do it that way, thanks!

Comment: I think this would compile fine, but the result would be a single insert containing the last values in each collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Iterators, this inserts as much records as possible

```
Iterator<String> iUserName = idvEUserName.iterator();
Iterator<String> iFullName = idvEFullName.iterator();
Iterator<String> iUserType = idvEUserType.iterator();

while(iUserName.hasNext() && iFullName.hasNext() && iUserType.hasNext()) {
    insert.setString(1, iUserName.next());
    insert.setString(2, iFullName.next());
    insert.setString(3, iUserType.next());
    insert.addBatch(); 
}
insert.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you do it does not work. You have to call do a single loop like so:

```
    String[] userNames = { "Herbert", "Daphne", "Donald J." };
    String[] fullNames = { "Herbert P.", "Daphne S.", "Donald J. T." };
    String[] userTypes = { "Janitor", "Construction Worker", "President" };

    PreparedStatement insert = getStatement();

    for (int i = 0; i < userNames.length; i++) {
      insert.setString(1, userNames[i]);
      insert.setString(2, fullNames[i]);
      insert.setString(3, userTypes[i]);
      insert.addBatch();
    }

    insert.executeUpdate();
```

Basically, your last call to `setString()` overrides the previous one.

Comment: But add an exit condition for the loop :)

Comment: If i am dealing with an arrayList can i use arrayList.size as opposed to the .length used for the String Array above?

Comment: @nice96 of course you can. Not knowing your Collection I used Iterator in my Solution, what handles all of them